# How to update fragment UI with data from SQLite in the onReceive() of Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, android-sqlite

I have a Firebase service that when new notification is in and the App is in the Foreground, I send a broadcast using a LocalBroadcastManager to fetch Data from SQLite and Update the Fragment UI(Recycler view).
I have cross checked to see that the Broadcast Receiver is actually sending broadcasts as I can Log to see the string extras I added to the intent. I have an updateUI() method that will fetch results from SQLite and update the UI.

I have cross checked to see that my updateUI() works on its own.(If I called it in the onResume() even without the broadcast receiver).

My problem however is that updating the UI in the onReceive() of the Broadcast receiver doesn't seems to work.

Here is excerpts of my Fragment and how I implemented it.

```
public class NoticeListFragment extends Fragment{


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateUI(); //In case data changes

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mNoticeBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("com.ultrasamad.htmcinside.NEW_NOTICE"));

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mNoticeBroadcastReceiver);
    }

    BroadcastReceiver mNoticeBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Check for intent filter
            if(intent.getAction().equals("com.ultrasamad.htmcinside.NEW_NOTICE")){
                //New notice has arrived, update UI
                String noticeTitle = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                Log.d(TAG, "Notice Title: " + noticeTitle);
                updateUI(); //Seems not to be working....
            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        //Inflate layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notice_list, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager linearManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearManager);

        updateUI();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void updateUI(){
        NoticeSource noticeSource = NoticeSource.get(getActivity());
        List<NoticeItem> notices = noticeSource.getNotices();

        if(mNoticeListAdapter == null){
            mNoticeListAdapter = new NoticeListAdapter(notices);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mNoticeListAdapter);
        }else{

            mNoticeListAdapter.setNotices(notices);
            mNoticeListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

In the onReceive() of Firebase Messaging where I created the broadcast.

```
Intent pushNotification = new Intent("com.ultrasamad.htmcinside.NEW_NOTICE");
                    pushNotification.putExtra("message", noticeTitle);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);
```

Adapter class as requested.

```
private class NoticeListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoticeViewHolder>{

    private List<NoticeItem> listItems;

    private NoticeListAdapter(List<NoticeItem> data) {
        this.listItems = data;
    }


    @Override
    public NoticeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.notice_lists_card, parent, false);
        return new NoticeViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NoticeViewHolder holder, int position){

        final NoticeItem noticeItem = listItems.get(position);
        holder.bindNotice(noticeItem);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    private void setNotices(List<NoticeItem> notices){
            listItems = notices;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try logging in the onReceive if the intent is received when sent from the firebase broadcast?

Comment: also, in your onPause:  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mNoticeBroadcastReceiver);. You are unregistering the broadcast when the activity is paused, are you sure that it's not unregistered when you receive the data?

Comment: Yh...I can log to see extras to prove that the broadcasting is working..

Comment: To the person who down voted my question, I will be glad to know why.

Comment: can you check the thread? add a log to the updateUI method Log.e("tag",         Thread.currentThread().getId() + ""); and log both when the method is called from onResume (ui thread) and from ur broadcast

Comment: try to invalidate the recyclerview and also check whether there is increment in your arraylist : List<NoticeItem> notices = noticeSource.getNotices()

Comment: @iGio90 with the thread log u suggested, I get id of 1 in the onReceive() and onResume().

Comment: That's good, so they are both running on UI. can you gist or post your adapter code please?

Comment: @iGio90 But the Adapter works well to mark the UI on its own. Just that I wanted to add broadcasting feature so that the UI is updated when there is a broadcast. So I doubt if it has something to do with the Adapter.

Comment: there are 2 possible issues in your code: 1) the list of the data that you fetch  here: List<NoticeItem> notices = noticeSource.getNotices(); is empty. 2) if the list is not empty, the issue is in the adapter

Comment: private void setNotices in your adapter. Add a Log.e("tag", "size: " + notices.size()); and paste here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142895/discussion-between-ultrasamad-and-igio90).

Answer (score -1):

1. check your parent activity of fragment . are u register that local broadcast receiver in activity then in fragment.

Comment: I already pointed out that I the broadcasting is working perfect, just that I can't seem to update the UI with data from SQLite.